# How to write test in swift for image loaded from URL using XCTEST?

Tags: swift, testing, uiimage, xctest

I am just starting with writing test cases for my code, I wanted to write test cases to test if the right image is loaded from the URL and also has cache implemented within in swift using XCTEST.

Code to test

```
func loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: String,completion: @escaping (UIImage)->()) {
        
        imageUrlString = urlString
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        image = nil
        if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) {
            self.image = imageFromCache
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, respones, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!) else { return }
                if self.imageUrlString == urlString {
                    self.image = imageToCache
                }
                imageCache.setObject(imageToCache, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                completion(self.image ?? UIImage())
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

One part of the test that I wrote

```
func test_DataImageLoadedFromHTTPSURL() {
        let expected = expectation(description: "Image from https did load")
        let viewer = CustomImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 250))
        viewer.loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: self.sut.imageUrl, completion: {_ in
            if viewer.image != nil {
                expected.fulfill()
            } else {
                XCTFail()
            }
        })
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 3.0, handler: nil)

    }
```

But here I feel the test is not perfect as we are only testing if nil or not, it would be great if somebody could guide me in the right way to go ahead with this test.

Comment: Your function loadImageUsingUrlString is not very well designed so it will be hard to write good tests for it. In your current test your are more testing URLSession than your own logic. To improve the design the function should do less, now it calls a completion handler, updates a property on self and the cache. I would suggest it only does the first one, call the completion handler and that you do the rest outside of this function. Also you are ignoring any error and you are not calling the completion handler at every exit point which makes the function hard to use.

Comment: Yes, it is doing a lot of things, I will refactor this function and so I set the cache outside of this function call, and then how do I validate this test, would one of the tests be if the image is set in the cache? If yes what do I validate it against to check if the right image is in cache or the right image is loaded from the URL?

Comment: Testing if the right image is downloaded is more about integration testing than unit testing so it's not relevant here. Focus on writing tests that calls the completion handler in different ways and verifies that the completion handler executes as expected

Comment: Sure, thank you, will refactor my code and go ahead with the tests to verify the completion handler. In the near future I will have to write Integration tests then how do I go about the same use case.